# Firebird 3 SQL windows function over()

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-3.0

I need help..
I have table orders like this

```
id,order_date,price,customer_id 
1 01.01.2001 100 1 
2 01.02.2001 0 1 
3 20.02.2001 0 1 
4 04.04.2001 200 1
```

I need select result like this

```
id,order_date,price,customer_id,somefield
1  01.01.2001  100   1           100
2  01.02.2001  0     1           100
3  20.02.2001  0     1           100 
3  04.04.2001  200   1           200
```

Try sql like this

```
 select a.id,order_date,
coalesce(a.price,0) price,
customer_id
sum(coalesce(a.price,0)) OVER (order by a.order_date) somefield,
     from tb_orders a
where a.customer_id=4583 and a.orderstate = 1
order by a.order_date
```

but result gives this

```
id,order_date,price,customer_id,somefield
1  01.01.2001  100   1           100
2  01.02.2001  0     1           100
3  20.02.2001  0     1           100 
3  04.04.2001  200   1           300
```

Comment: Why do you expect that last row to have `someField = 200`? 100 + 200 = 300, so the result as returned by Firebird is correct given the query you use. Also, please edit your title so it summarizes your question (_"Firebird 3 SQL windows function over()"_ tells us nothing about your question, just what you're using)

Answer (score 3):

You could create subgroup:

```
SELECT *, MAX(price) OVER(PARTITION BY grp) AS somefield
FROM  (
    select a.id,order_date,
          coalesce(a.price,0) price,
          customer_id,
          sum(CASE WHEN price = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (order by a.order_date) grp
    from tb_orders a
    where a.customer_id=4583 
      and a.orderstate = 1
) sub
order by order_date;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=64ef79189056a240690b97c57e7a2843)**

Comment: Thank's your answer but not work for me. Wrong result

Comment: @Tester2019 Please post your data. Query is correct: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=64ef79189056a240690b97c57e7a2843 If you are using it without `WHERE` then you have to partition by customer_id

Comment: Thank you I found my mistake null value on price columnt

Comment: @Tester2019 you are new, you can not vote yet. However upvote is not crucial, crucial is "answer acception" - that us green checkmark button UNDER upvote and downvote ones, and it should be accessible to you

Comment: @Tester2019 [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)